# NS2: traffic splitting in a node, how to do?

Tags: ns2

i was wondering if, in NS2, if there is a node with 1 incoming link and 2 outgoin link, there is any way to split traffic in a node so that one part goes over one link and the remaining part goes over other link?

Comment: Google, ns2 split traffic https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+split+traffic ...

Comment: @KnudLarsen I did that, but there is no specific answer, did I miss any obvious answer?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+split+traffic is about searching a lot of hints with Google yourself. Two more hint about "split traffic in a node" : http://network-simulator-ns-2.7690.n7.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=2&query=split+traffic+in+a+node&n=2 ... and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split+traffic+in+a+node ...